# One time password

Tags: users

I am using [profile2 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) for user registration.How to create one time password when user is register. Is there any module for this?

If i want to create it by custom then how to do it.Please help me if any body knows.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this, I've the same requirement now.

Comment: @james i have created a new module with help of Login One time.you can also take help with Login One time module.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for the [Login One time](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_one_time) module

> Login one time provides the ability to email one-time login links to users. You can also choose the pages they will land on.

Similar module is [One-time login](https://www.drupal.org/project/one_time_login)

> This module adds two operations to the form at Administration >> People: "Send one-time login link to the selected users" and "Download CSV of one-time login URLs for the selected users".

Comment: No, I want One time password when user is register that send to user email and he/she can login with that password and then can update his password.

Answer (score 0):

This [module OTP Verification](https://www.drupal.org/project/otp_verification) helps you, One registration with phone number, it sends you OTP via SMS to verify, SMS gateways are plugable.